# Vaadin 7 createEntityItem and addentity to JPAContainer Eclipse shows syntax error in code

Tags: jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0, vaadin

I am trying to add a new item using formlayout form to JPAContainer in vaadin 7. I use this code snippet:

```
String paramDAO = "PersonDAO";        //this parameter can be acquired from url, http request, data file and etc
Class<?> TC = null;      //DAO class

InitialContext ic;
ic = new InitialContext();
TO = ic.lookup("java:app/MyDAOProject/"+paramDao);   
// PersonDAO class extends JPAContainer<PersonEntity>

container =  (JPAContainer<?>) TO;
T = container.getEntityClass();

if(event.getButton() == newButton)
    {               
        final EntityItem newRecord = container.createEntityItem(T.newInstance());        //eclipse shows syntax error here              
        final EditorWindow editor = new EditorWindow(newRecord, T, visibleColumns, this.entytiPropFactory);

        editor.setCaption("New record");
        editor.addListener(new EditorSavedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void editorSaved(EditorSavedEvent event) 
                    {
                        container.addEntity(newRecord.getEntity());           //eclipse shows syntax error here
                        new Notification("New record created.", null, Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION, true).show(Page.getCurrent());
                    }               
            }                   
        );              
        UI.getCurrent().addWindow(editor);
    }
```

The main idea is that I want to create a unified vaadin table with editing form that fits for mostly entities (data base tables) in my project. So I pass dao object name as string parameter (don't ask why) and then i lookup it through jndi service. The dao object is tied with entity and extends JPAcontainer<*entityClass*> class. This approach worked perfectly in Vaadin 6 version with JPAContainer 2.2.0 but after migrating to Vaadin 7 and JPAContainer 3.0.0 eclipse throws me a syntax error in these lines (errors are in comments respectively every line below):

```
final EntityItem newRecord = container.createEntityItem(T.newInstance()); 
//The method createEntityItem(capture#9-of ?) in the type JPAContainer<capture#9-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#10-of ?)

container.addEntity(newRecord.getEntity());
//The method addEntity(capture#12-of ?) in the type JPAContainer<capture#12-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your declaration of the container variable is something like this:
`JPAContainer<?> container;`

So your warnings could be avoided by declaring the container variable like this:
`JPAContainer<Object> container;` 
 Or this: 
`JPAContainer container;`

Here you will find some additional information about wildcards in java generics: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html